# Installing “SoX” (Sound eXchange) via the Terminal in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, unix

I’m new to installing applications via the “Terminal,” so excuse my absolute ignorance on the subject.

I want to install [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) (Sound eXchange), so I can do some ninja audio editing. First I installed git, then I installed SoX. I didn’t get any error messages and the installation has spawned a sox-folder in my Users/myName-folder.

However when I use the program by typing `sox` in the “Terminal,” nothing happens, all I get is “command not found.”

Does anybody know how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: According to SoX instructions, you need to run autoreconf -i first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably better on superuser?  Based on the and `/Users` I am guessing you are on Mac OS X?

If all you did was `git clone` it down, you have the *source code* to the application and *not* a binary.

You would need to `cd sox-folder` and then do the `./configure && make && make install`  dance. But as you say you are new to this, that might be a bit rough.

If you are on  Mac OS X then something like [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) might help you here, as they both have packages/ports for SoX. If you are not on Mac OS X, most distribution of *nix will have a package available (i.e. `yum install sox`, `apt-get install sox`, etc…) but more information would be needed.

If you just want to run sox, [go here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/sox/14.3.2/) and grab the precompiled Mac OS X Binary: `sox-14.3.2-macosx.zip`. To compile what you have you will need  `autoconf`, `automake`, etc… Basically the entire `autotools` toolchain, and that is probably overkill assuming you just want to run the utility.

Comment: Thx for helping me out. There is no configure-file in the sox-folder, however there was a Makefile.am, bash spits out the following when I run it:
./Makefile.am: line 3: ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile.am: line 5: SUBDIRS: command not found
./Makefile.am: line 6: DIST_SUBDIRS: command not found
RM: =: No such file or directory
RM: rm: No such file or directory
RM: -f: No such file or directory
./Makefile.am: line 12: dist_man_MANS: command not found
./Makefile.am: line 13: EXTRA_DIST: command not found
./Makefile.am: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
 etc.

Comment: since you have the raw src code to Sox, you are going to need the complete auto* toolchain, as well as all of the Dev Tools, gcc, etc..  Do you have Xcode installed?  I am guessing you just want to use SOX and don't need the bleeding edge version.  I'll update my answer with a link to what you probably need.

Comment: @timkl Just install Homebrew using the [one-liner](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation) and run `brew install sox` afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

I used Homebrew to install sox for me with the command

```
brew install sox
```

And, assuming I am using the `bash` shell instead of the default `zsh` as of 2020, I would add the following to the hidden .bash_profile in the home directrly for sox to be picked up

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

This I normally do after installing Homebrew for the first time. You only need to add this to the .bash_profile once.

Answer (score 2):

Check if it's in the path

```
which sox
```

try launching it using the complete path.
/usr/local/.../sox

check permissions to the sox binary.

Answer (score 2):

[This article explains in detail](http://quadloops.com/blog/installing-sox-in-ubuntu-12-04-and-working-with-ogg-and-vorbis-formats/) to have SoX running in Ubuntu. It worked for me, so I think it should work for you too

**Edit:**

Simplest way in ubuntu would be to run these two commands

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins libasound2-python libsox-fmt-all

sudo apt-get install sox
```

If you are in some other Linux, like CentOS or you need support for Vorbis and Ogg, you will have to compile from source, found by following the link above

Answer (score 1):

Install the App

1. Press Command+Space and type Terminal and press enter/return key.
2. Run in Terminal app: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   < /dev/null 2> /dev/null and press enter/return key. Wait for the
   command to finish.
3. Run: brew install sox

Courtesy: http://macappstore.org/sox/

Answer (score 0):

`brew install sox` works for me.

Comment: Assuming Homebrew is installed first